# navigation from one page to another in ionic2

Tags: angular, navigation, ionic2

I am using show() in html file to navigate from one page to another this is going well on next page but showing error co.show is not a function. please check the screenshot attached.

[image]

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import {Nextpage} from '../../pages/nextpage/nextpage';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';



@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
  
})
export class HomePage {
posts:any;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public http: Http) {
   
   this.navCtrl=navCtrl;
  
   this.http.get('https://www.reddit.com/r/gifs/new/.json?limit=10').map(res => res.json()).subscribe(
    response => {
        this.posts = response.data.children;
  console.log(this.posts);
    },
    err => {
        console.log("Oops!");
    });
 
 function show(){
 this.navCtrl.push(Nextpage);
 }
 }
  }
```

```html
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar color="color1">
    <ion-title>Home</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

 <ion-content  >
 
  <ion-slides style="max-height:250px! Important; max-width: 100%! Important;"  autoplay="5000" loop="true" speed="3000">
    <ion-slide  >
      <img src="../../assets/img/seven.png">
    </ion-slide>
    <ion-slide >
      <img src="../../assets/img/seven.png">
    </ion-slide>
    <ion-slide >
      <img src="../../assets/img/seven.png">
    </ion-slide>
  </ion-slides>
 
 

   <ion-list class="family-icon-scroller">
   <ion-list-header>
   <b>Recent Activities</b>
   </ion-list-header>
    <ion-item (click)="show();" class="family-icon" *ngFor="let post of posts">
     
  <img  [src]="post.data.url" />
      <p style="text-align:center; padding-top:1.5%;">{{post.data.author}}</p>
   
   </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
  
  
  <ion-list class="family-icon-scroller">
  <ion-list-header>
   <b>Samples</b>
   </ion-list-header>
    <ion-item class="family-icon" *ngFor="let post of posts">
      <img [src]="post.data.url" />
       <p style="text-align:center; padding-top:1.5%;">{{post.data.author}}</p>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
  
  <ion-list class="family-icon-scroller">
  <ion-list-header>
   <b>Practice tests</b>
   </ion-list-header>
    <ion-item class="family-icon" *ngFor="let post of posts">
      <img  [src]="post.data.url" />
      <p style="text-align:center; padding-top:1.5%;">{{post.data.author}}</p>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>


<!--- today
https://www.reddit.com/r/gifs/new/.json?limit=10
   
<div  class="myBackground">
   <h5 class="title" style="padding-left:2%;" >Recent Activities</h5>
 <ul class="family-icon-scroller">
    <li (click)="Showpage();" class="family-icon" ><img src="../../assets/img/Grammar.jpg" /></li>
    <li (click)="showpage();"  class="family-icon"><img src="../../assets/img/Grammar.jpg" /></li>
    <li (click)="showpage();"  class="family-icon"><img src="../../assets/img/Grammar.jpg" /></li>
    <li (click)="showpage();"  class="family-icon"><img src="../../assets/img/Grammar.jpg" /></li>
    <li ui-sref="next" class="family-icon"><img src="../../assets/img/Grammar.jpg" /></li>
    <li ui-sref="next" class="family-icon"><img src="../../assets/img/Grammar.jpg" /></li>
    <li ui-sref="next" class="family-icon"><img src="../../assets/img/Grammar.jpg" /></li>
    <li ui-sref="next" class="family-icon"><img src="../../assets/img/Grammar.jpg" /></li>
    <li ui-sref="next" class="family-icon"><img src="../../assets/img/Grammar.jpg" /></li>
    <li ui-sref="next" class="family-icon"><img src="../../assets/img/Grammar.jpg" /></li>
    <li ui-sref="next" class="family-icon"><img src="../../assets/img/Grammar.jpg" /></li>

</ul>
</div>

<div class="myBackground">
   <h5 class="title" style="padding-left:2%;">Courses</h5>

 <ul class="family-icon-scroller">
    <li class="family-icon"><img ng-src="img/Grammar8.jpg" /></li>
    <li class="family-icon"><img ng-src="img/Grammar8.jpg" /></li>
    <li class="family-icon"><img ng-src="img/Grammar8.jpg" /></li>
    <li class="family-icon"><img ng-src="img/Grammar8.jpg" /></li>
    <li class="family-icon"><img ng-src="img/Grammar8.jpg" /></li>
    <li class="family-icon"><img ng-src="img/Grammar8.jpg" /></li>
    <li class="family-icon"><img ng-src="img/Grammar8.jpg" /></li>
    <li class="family-icon"><img ng-src="img/Grammar8.jpg" /></li>
    <li class="family-icon"><img ng-src="img/Grammar8.jpg" /></li>
    <li class="family-icon"><img ng-src="img/Grammar8.jpg" /></li>
    <li class="family-icon"><img ng-src="img/Grammar8.jpg" /></li>

</ul>
</div>

<div class="myBackground">
   <h5 class="title" style="padding-left:2%;" >Practice tests</h5>

 <ul class="family-icon-scroller">
    <li class="family-icon"><img ng-src="img/test1.jpg" /></li>
    <li class="family-icon"><img ng-src="img/test1.jpg" /></li>
    <li class="family-icon"><img ng-src="img/test1.jpg" /></li>
    <li class="family-icon"><img ng-src="img/test1.jpg" /></li>
    <li class="family-icon"><img ng-src="img/test1.jpg" /></li>
    <li class="family-icon"><img ng-src="img/test1.jpg" /></li>
    

</ul>
</div>
-->

 </ion-content>
```

I have also made entries of the nextpage in app.module.ts file. Not able to know where i am going wrong.

Comment: you need to show the relevant code [mcve]

Comment: noo.. paste the code not screenshots.. edit it into your question

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/posts/43870165/edit

Comment: paste the component side code as well

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is you defined function *within* the constructor.

```
export class HomePage {
posts:any;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public http: Http) {
   //you dont need to reinitialize navCtrl here since you injected using access specifier.      
   this.http.get('https://www.reddit.com/r/gifs/new/.json?limit=10').map(res => res.json()).subscribe(
    response => {
        this.posts = response.data.children;
        console.log(this.posts);
    },
    err => {
        console.log("Oops!");
    });
 }
//should be here
 show(){
    this.navCtrl.push(Nextpage);
    }
  }
```

More on typescript classes: [(docs)](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html)

**Side note**: It is always better to do async operations like the http call in lifecyclehooks like `ngOnInit` rather than the constructor.

Comment: ah my bad.. it shouldnt have the keyword function..will edit it

Answer (score 0):

You have to put your function outside the constructor

And you have to declare your function like:

```
show(){
  this.navCtrl.push(Nextpage);
}
```

If you use:

```
function show(){
      this.navCtrl.push(Nextpage);
    }
```

You will get this error:

> Unexpected token. A constructor, method, accessor, or property was
>   expected.

Answer (score 0):

declare nextpage in  app.module  component and try.